# mongoose conflict when using all positional operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema which looks like this:

```
players: [{
    name: String,
    score: Number
}]
```

In the same query I'm trying to set all names to smth, and remove all scores. The query looks like this:

```
Game.updateOne({code}, {
    $set: {
        "players.0.name": "n1",
        "players.1.name": "n2",
    }
    $unset: {
        "players.$[].score": ""
    }
```

When I execute it, I get the following error:

```
MongoError: Updating the path 'players.0.name' would create a conflict at 'players'
```

However, if I modify the unset part like this:

```
    $unset: {
        "players.0.score": "",
        "players.1.score": "",
    }
```

Then it's working correctly.

Is it a bug that I cannot use $[] operator there? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is that you cannot have same field in `$set` and `$unset` at the same time.

Here you have different fields but you use `$[]` operator which means all array elements. So it assumes you will unset `name` also, hence that error occurred. But when you specify positional operator, you specify particular element in the array. So you don't get that conflict.

You can reproduce the same with

```
db.getCollection('test').update({},{
     $set: {
        "players.0.name": "n1",
        "players.1.name": "n2",
    },
    $unset: {
        "players.0.name": ""
    }
    })
```

Comment: I see, so it's just too dumb to realize that 'players.$[].score' does not modify any player's name :)

Comment: `$[]` means all array elements. That's the reason. As you said, if you use particular position, you ll not get that error